# React: Functional Components, passing and executing functions to event-listeners

Tags: reactjs, events, reference

I have a functional React component, in which I want to trigger a function when clicking on an IonicIcon icon. Now, there exist two different methods how to execute that function:
I can just pass a reference to my method inside {} brackets, or I can pass it to function, but I don't understand why and how this works behind the scenes, and which one is better, method 1 or method 2?

```
const checkIcon = () => {
    let showIcon = null;
    if (actualState.showInputField === false) {
        showIcon = (
           <IoIosAddCircleOutline onClick = {() => {
               toggleInput();
            } 
        }
            />
        )
    } else {
        showIcon = (
            <IoIosRemoveCircleOutline onClick = {toggleInput}
            />
        )
    }
    return showIcon;
}


const toggleInput = () => {
    changeState({...actualState, showInputField: !actualState.showInputField});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variant 1 `onClick={() => toggleInput()}` is best used if you want to forward something else to your function besides the `event` object.

```
<div onClick={(event) => doSomething(event, index, extra_data)} />
```

Variant 2 `onClick={toggleInput}` is the standard usage of event handlers. It will just get the `event` object as its first argument.

Comment: Also, variant 1 creates a new callback on every render, which can lead to re-rendering of components further down the line as explained in https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html